# How to get ˚ in openCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to write `˚` (degree character) in my image. I'm using Python and OpenCV.
The character, however, is shown as `??`. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

read=np.ones((500,500))
temp=100
read=cv2.putText(read,'{:>8.2f} ℃'.format(temp),(20,100), font, 2,(255,255,255),4,cv2.LINE_AA)
plt.imshow(read)
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: `putText` (or, rather, the Hershey font) only supports a sub-set of ASCII  characters. Have you tried using PIL's `draw.text` to write the `unicode` (`u"\u00B0"`) for the degree character?

Comment: I didn't try PIL

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you, eldesgraciado,
PIL works well

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
    
    font_path = 'C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf'           
    font_size = 48                                      
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)     
    
    read=np.ones((500,500))
    temp=100
    img=Image.fromarray(read)
    draw=ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((0, 50),'{:>9.2f} ˚C'.format(temp), font=font, fill=255)
    read=np.array(img)
    plt.imshow(read)
```